# Unity shader，Zwrite On is not working. i cant see my object in scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

I set ZWrite to On for my object in Unity's shader and set it to the Geometry render queue. However, this object is not visible in the Scene, and I can see through Frame Debug that the Zwrite for this object is off.

`Shader "Bump" {
Properties {
_MainTex("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

```
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "RenderPipeline"="UniversalPipeline" "Queue"="Geometry" }

    HLSLINCLUDE
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"
        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Lighting.hlsl"

        CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        CBUFFER_END
    ENDHLSL

    Pass {
        Name "Example"
        Tags { "LightMode"="UniversalForward" }
        ZWrite On
        ZTest LEqual

        HLSLPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        struct a2v{
            float4 positionOS   : POSITION;
            float2 uv       : TEXCOORD0;
            float3 normal   : NORMAL;
            float4 tangent  : TANGENT;
        };

        struct v2f{
            float4 positionCS   : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv       : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 t2w0     : TEXCOORD1;
            float4 t2w1     : TEXCOORD2;
            float4 t2w2     : TEXCOORD3;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;


        v2f vert(a2v IN) {
            v2f OUT;

            VertexPositionInputs positionInputs = GetVertexPositionInputs(IN.positionOS.xyz);
            VertexNormalInputs normal_inputs = GetVertexNormalInputs(IN.normal, IN.tangent);
            OUT.positionCS = positionInputs.positionCS;
            OUT.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(IN.uv, _MainTex);
            OUT.t2w0 = float4(normal_inputs.tangentWS.x, normal_inputs.bitangentWS.x, normal_inputs.normalWS.x, positionInputs.positionWS.x);
            OUT.t2w1 = float4(normal_inputs.tangentWS.y, normal_inputs.bitangentWS.y, normal_inputs.normalWS.y, positionInputs.positionWS.y);
            OUT.t2w2 = float4(normal_inputs.tangentWS.z, normal_inputs.bitangentWS.z, normal_inputs.normalWS.z, positionInputs.positionWS.z);
            return OUT;
        }

        half4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target {
            float3 posWS = float3(IN.t2w0.w, IN.t2w1.w, IN.t2w2.w);
            float3x3 t2wMatrix = float3x3(IN.t2w0.xyz, IN.t2w1.xyz, IN.t2w2.xyz);
            Light light = GetMainLight();
            half3 lightDirWS = normalize(light.direction);
            half3 viewDirWs = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - posWS);
            half3 halfDirWs = normalize(lightDirWS + viewDirWs);

            half4 baseMap = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
            half3 finalColor = baseMap.rgb;

            
            return half4(finalColor, 1);
        }
        
        ENDHLSL
    }
}
```

}
`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffOP7.png)

how can i make object in geometry queue visible in scene.

Answer (score 0):

Your shader has error at line this line:

```
half4 baseMap = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
```

It should be IN.uv. You have wrongly entered just uv.